# if statement condition depending on response psychopy

Tags: python, psychopy

In my experiment, participants have to make a series of ratings in a visual rating scale.

First I initialize the screen and add the corresponding visual components. My variable `recall` creates the rating scale which provides 2 choices: "Yes" and "No".

Later, with the `vasTitle` variable a title is created which asks 'Do you remember this painting?' and they have to answer "Yes" or "No" on the scale that appears on the same screen as the question.

Now I would like to condition my `recall` statement depending on whether the participant answered "Yes" or "No" but I have no idea on how to do it. If participants answer "No" I would like to address their confidence of their previous answer (this is where the problem is, in this condition).

This I do by creating another scale where they have to answer either "yes" or "no" they feel confident about their previous answer to whether they recall the painting or not. When I run my code it breaks at the moment I condition the `recall` variable. You can see at the end of the code what I have tried, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
from psychopy import visual

# Intialize screen
win = visual.Window(size=(1440, 900), fullscr=True, screen=0, allowGUI=False, allowStencil=False, monitor='testMonitor', color=[0,0,0], 
colorSpace='rgb', blendMode='avg', useFBO=True, units='deg')

# Initialize Visual Components

recall = visual.RatingScale(win, choices=("Yes", "No"), markerStart=0.5, singleClick=False, 
disappear=False, respKeys=['left', 'right'], showAccept=False, acceptKeys='up')

vasTitle = visual.TextStim(win=win, ori=0, name='vasTitle', text=u'+', font=u'Arial',
pos=[0, 5], height=1.0, wrapWidth=None, color=u'white', colorSpace='rgb', opacity=1,
depth=0.0)

vasScore = visual.TextStim(win=win, ori=0, name='vasScore', text=u'+', font=u'Arial',
pos=[0, -3], height=1.0, wrapWidth=None, color=u'white', colorSpace='rgb', opacity=1,
depth=0.0)

confidence2 = visual.RatingScale(win, low=1, high=6, labels=("Sure I don't know", "Sure I know"), 
marker='glow', markerColor='LightGrey', singleClick=False, noMouse=True,
showValue=False, markerStart = 3.5, showAccept=False,
leftKeys='left', rightKeys='right', acceptKeys = 'up', 
disappear=False)

# Start trial of experiment
for tr in range(1):
# Recall
    recall.reset()
    vasTitle.setText('Do you remember this painting?')
    while recall.noResponse:
        vasTitle.draw()
        recall.draw()
        win.flip()
    showText(text='+', time=0.5, FrameRate=Exp.FrameRate)

    if recall.Response == "No": #PROBLEM HERE
        confidence2.reset()
        vasTitle.setText('How sure are you of your previous answer?')
        while confidence2.noResponse:
            vasTitle.draw()
            confidence2.draw()
            vasScore.setText('%i' %(confidence2.getRating()))
            vasScore.draw()
            win.flip()
        showText(text='+', time=0.5, FrameRate=Exp.FrameRate)
```

Comment: "problem here" - WHAT is the problem?

Comment: Did you `print(recall.Reponse)` to make sure it's either `Yes`or `No` ?
You might want to try `if recall.Response() == "No"` instead. But I did'nt find the `Reponse` in the doc of this package...

Comment: The problem is that my if statement in "problem here" does not work. It stops and doesn't continue to my question and to my confidence2 scale

Comment: Where did you find how to use `recall.noResponse` and `recall.Response` ? @MDClaudio

Comment: @GwendalGrelier I tried using the print(recall.Response) and it indicates that the 'RatingScale' object has no Response attribute. I feel this is odd if in my while statement from before I use recall.noResponse and it works.

Comment: @GwendalGrelier I only found here in stack overflow a code with the 'noResponse' attribute for that particular moment before I had to condition depending on the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should have done a little bit more reasearch on how to use this library. In your code `recall` is an instance of `visual.RatingScale`. It seems that the `while recall.noResponse` loop is ended when a definitive answer is validated by the user (up key). When this loop is ended you can access different property:

```
while recall.noResponse:
    vasTitle.draw()
    recall.draw()
    win.flip()
    # this loop is ended when the 'up' key is pressed to validate the answer
rating = recall.getRating() # Stores the final answer
decisionTime = recall.getRT() # Stores the decision time (sec)
choiceHistory = recall.getHistory() # Stores tulpes of (answer, time)
```

Here are some links to help you:

github project https://github.com/psychopy/versions/blob/master/psychopy/visual/ratingscale.py
  api doc for RatingScale() http://www.psychopy.org/api/visual/ratingscale.html#psychopy.visual.RatingScale